# Joining Pandas dataframe on hour range

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes, one with weather information, given hourly, and one with bus arrival data, given approximately every minute or so.

I want to join the dataframes so bus data is associated with weather for that hour e.g. bus data between 1pm and 2pm on 01/06/2012 will be associated with corresponding weather data.

e.g Bus Data

```
DateTime                LineID    Longitude    Latitude
2013-01-01 00:00:27     4.0       -6.279000    53.416683
2013-01-01 00:01:33     4.0       -6.279321    53.416697
2013-01-01 00:02:44     4.0       -6.279435    53.416492
2013-01-01 00:03:28     4.0       -6.279553    53.416596
2013-01-01 00:04:31     4.0       -6.279868    53.416530
```

e.g Weather Data

```
DateTime                Temperature    Rainfall 
2013-01-01 00:00:00     10             0    
2013-01-01 01:00:00     10             0    
2013-01-01 02:00:00     11             0
2013-01-01 03:00:00     11             0.1
2013-01-01 04:00:00     11             0.2
```

Is there a way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you expected results?  I don't see any PM times nor 1-6-2012 data in you sample data?  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need `pd.merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(bus_df,weather_df, on='DateTime')
```

Output:

```
             DateTime  LineID  Longitude   Latitude  Temperature  Rainfall
0 2013-01-01 00:00:27     4.0  -6.279000  53.416683           10       0.0
1 2013-01-01 00:01:33     4.0  -6.279321  53.416697           10       0.0
2 2013-01-01 00:02:44     4.0  -6.279435  53.416492           10       0.0
3 2013-01-01 00:03:28     4.0  -6.279553  53.416596           10       0.0
4 2013-01-01 00:04:31     4.0  -6.279868  53.416530           10       0.0
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need. I am getting an error saying "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'merge_asof'" though when I try to run?

Comment: What version of Pandas are you on?

Comment: [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof) New in version 0.19.0